# Neither Alert nor Console.log firing within JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, alert, console.log

```
    $.getJSON("/example-json.js", function(result){
        alert(result);
        console.log(result.backgrounds[0].image);
    });
```

Is there any reason the alert or console.log wouldn't work here? I have this method within the History.bind event binder but I do not think that is the issue because I was still not able to get an alert or log the result to the console even after moving the JSON request outside of the event binder.

I know the GET request is firing correctly as I can see it within the console, it is the alert and console.log that for some reason are not working for me.

Comment: If you have Chrome developers tools or Firebug check the Network tab. Is the request failing?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?  Also, stupid question, but does that json file actually exist where you think it does?

Comment: Yes, I actually just went in and edited the original post. The GET request is firing correctly and I can see the JSON file and it's contents within the console.

Comment: Make sure in your developer tools (console) settings you have it set to display "all" and not just "errors."

Comment: I do have it set to ALL, still not getting anything in the console regarding the result of the function.

Comment: I also do not think this is an error with the JSON file because even if I try alerting or logging a hard coded string to the console, it will not fire if it's within the JSON request.

Comment: And outside of the getJSON call...are you able to alert, or console.log then?

Comment: Yes, all other instances outside of the JSON call work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found the problem, I was using single quotes within my JSON file and when changing those to single quotes, the alert() and console.log() began firing. I'm not really sure why using single quotes would have an effect on the success function of the JSON method, though?

Answer (score 0):

See if it works like this:

```
$.getJSON("/example-json.js").done(function(result) {
    alert(result);
    console.log(result.backgrounds[0].image);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to have any effect.